# How can I sync history of Safari?

Tags: data-synchronization, safari, browser-history

Question is in the header. I know that Google Chrome stores his history in sqlite database, and there's impossible to sync Chrome's history. Can I do this with Safari? I didn't find this option.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, I would like to synchronize Safari history between computers and maybe mobile devices if possible. So browsers on iMac and MacBook has a same browsing history. Now, each browser has its own history. It would be convenient. When you enter an address or search query - autofill works, and you can do things faster.

Comment: Well, I tried this using Dropbox to sync the History.plist file through symlinks, but it doesn't seem to work how I'd like. If anyone managed to get this working, let me know, I'd really enjoy Safari syncing my browser history throughout the devices I use (Mac mini at work, MacBook Pro at home).

Comment: I tried Dropbox too. Finally, I've considered to cancel this idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody heard you, because this is now baked in. Your iCloud account will sync bookmarks, browser history, and even tabs in Yosemite and iOS 8.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I think this question can be closed as solved.